# Is it possible to set timer events in jquery w/o any plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer

I want a jquery timer like setTimeout/setinterval to call a function repeatedly for every particular no. of seconds. I have tried both. But it call only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.settimeout) is called only once after the elapsed time whereas [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is called repeatedly. For example if you want to invoke some function every 5 seconds:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    someFunction();    
}, 5000);
```

It doesn't require any plugins, it is pure javascript. Even if there were jQuery plugins they would eventually use `setTimeout/setInterval`.

Comment: Note that passing could also be done directly in this case, i.e. `setInterval(someFunction, 5000)`.

Comment: I have tried like this..but it's not working.. window.setInterval( function() {
  alert("Hello");
  
 }, 1000 );

Comment: @Anish, no idea but this works perfectly fine. Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jQR7C/ You probably have some other code that you are not showing and which is interfering. Or some js errors. Please show a full example allowing us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: yeah..i have find the reason...it's because of other code that i'm using.Thanx for quick reply..

Comment: @Anish, glad you found the problem. You might then close this question unless you have some other issues with it?